# Create clickable zones in image?

Tags: c#, winforms, image

I have to implement a solution for which I'm not really sure how to proceed as I don't know this language (C#) very well.

Let me explain : 
The goal is to have something that allows the user to choose a zone from an item (which has a circular form). 
So the idea was put an image with numbers on the zone (so in the end it would look like a clock), and get the zone from the number the user would click.

So my question is : is it possible to create clickable zones in an image ?
(Or if you have another solution for this functionnality, I'm open-minded)

Thanks in advance !

EDIT >> This is for a WinForm application, not a website.

Comment: Is this a website or a WinForms application?

Comment: It is for a winforms application, I indeed forgot to mention that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks you all for your answers, there are interesting things in them.

Unfortunately, as I had to develop this very fast, I just created an image on which I would catch the onclick event and then catch the zones the user clicked using Cursor.Position like this :

```
int X = pictureBox.PointToClient(Cursor.Position).X;
int Y = pictureBox.PointToClient(Cursor.Position).Y;
```

Maybe not the "cleaner" way to do it, but it works !
Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just implement something like this?

```c#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Zone
{
    public Region Region { get; private set; }
    public Action<MouseEventArgs> Click { get; private set; }

    public Zone(Region zoneRegion, Action<MouseEventArgs> click)
    {
        this.Region = zoneRegion;
        this.Click = click;
    }
}

public class PictureBoxWithClickableZones : PictureBox
{
    private readonly List<Zone> zones = new List<Zone>();

    public void AddZone(Zone zone)
    {
        if (zone == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("zone");

        this.zones.Add(zone);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseClick(e);

        foreach (var zone in this.zones.Where(zone => zone.Region.IsVisible(e.Location)))
            zone.Click(e);
    }
}
```

If you have enought time you can make appropriate components and use then even in Visual Studio's WinForms Designer.

Comment: I know this is old, but since I have not found any more recent solution I wanted to give this a try. I have one question, how do you add zones ? I tried creating a zone but don't know what to put for the `action` parameter, could you give a a small code example on how to create and add a zone ?

Answer (score 1):

Although it isn't all that popular anymore, [you can use the `<map>` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp) to do this.

```
<img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap" />

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="sun.htm" alt="Sun" />
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="mercur.htm" alt="Mercury" />
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="venus.htm" alt="Venus" />
</map>
```

**Edit:**

Since this requires a WinForms solution, perhaps this article can help you.

[C# Windows Forms ImageMap Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2820/C-Windows-Forms-ImageMap-Control)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately I'm building a WinForms application, no a website (as I forgot to mention in the first post)

Answer (score 0):

Looking into Html imagemaps.

will take you about 5 minutes to learn how to use is.

In the  tag you can apply and map attribute
Than define your map regions and links

Here's a quick google response
http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/imagemap.shtml

Comment: Same as above, I forgot to mention I'm building a winforms application, not a website, so this can't be used :s