# Creating clickable C# image map in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, imagemap

I'm trying to develop a basic C# winforms app with a clickable image map as its focus. That is, an image where a certain section is clickable and will open a new form. For example the image could be a chessboard, and clicking on a certain square will perform the action of opening a new form.

I hope this concept is clear. I've looked at similar questions on S.O. and could not find a workable solution.

Cheers

Comment: The listed duplicate is _not_ a duplicate.  That answer doesn't even come close to helping someone sort this out.

Comment: Thank you! Helpful rather than dismissive

Answer (score 3):

My solution would be to leverage the `MouseUp` event on whatever control holds the image.  When you get that click, resolve the position of `e.Location` (MouseUp gives you `MouseEventArgs`) down to the control using `PointToClient()`.

Once you have that `Point`, you need only determine if it's in a valid `Rectangle`, and if it is, launch the appropriate form.

**Edit:**

You can use the forms designer to add a control to the form, such as a `Panel` and then add an event handler to that control, such as `OnMouseUp`.  It would look something like this:

```
private void panel1_MouseUp(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //your code goes here
}
```

That event handler will be called whenever the user clicks on your panel and releases the mouse button.

In that event handler, you could have something like this:

```
if (e.Button.Equals(MouseButtons.Left))
{
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10, 10, 100, 100);  //this is the zone you wish to react the user clicking on
    if (rect.Contains(e.Location))
    {
        //show your form
    }
}
```

`e.Location` is going to be the location of the mouse at the moment the button was released, in coordinates corresponding to the control in question, in this case `panel1`.

You will probably want a more elegant solution if there are many regions to consider, such as keeping a list or array of `Rectangle` and looping over them.

Comment: Could you please explain this in a little more detail? I think I understand what you mean and would prefer to use this method. I have picbox and x/y coordinates from the mouseMove event.

Comment: If it's a click you want to capture, then use MouseUp or MouseDown.  Don't use MouseMove...it fires constantly.

Comment: How can I capture the X / Y coordinates(location range) without mouseMove?

Comment: That's what you get in `MouseEventArgs`...`e.Location` (already translated to client coords)

Answer (score 2):

Basically you would handle the click event on the image and get the coordinates of the click point. Then you have to evaluate it to the values you need in order to do something or not.

Alternatively you could use "zones".

There is already a similar q&a that could be what you're looking for:

[Create clickable zones in image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194017/create-clickable-zones-in-image)

**Edit:**

There is an image-map control project on codeproject at the following url:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2820/C-Windows-Forms-ImageMap-Control

Although it's .NET 1.0, it shouldn't be a big deal to adapt it to your needs.