# Create different clickable parts on one Background Image in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I need to create a C# Windows Form Application with one image in the form background. Clicking on 10 different parts of the image will lead to different events/actions occurring. How do you make the different parts of the image clickable?

Thank you!

Comment: You could add 10 empty **PictureBox** controls, resize and place them where you want, set Cursor to **Hand**, and then assign your events to each of the control.

Comment: I don't think adding 10 controls to the form is a good idea at all. Take a look at this to get an idea of where to go with it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21286617/creating-clickable-c-sharp-image-map-in-winforms

Comment: _Clicking on 10 different parts.._ What kind of 'parts' do you want? rectangles or shapes or colored areas..?? There are many ways to do it but to find the best one we need to know more!

Comment: @Yatrix I thought about that solution but it's a bit more complicated.

Comment: @TaW They are rectangular boxes in the image that represent different colors....let me know if you need anything else

Answer (score 2):

In the simplest case all you nee to do is create a

```
List<Rectangle> rects  = new List<Rectangle>();
```

Fill them with the coordinates:

```
   rects.Add(new Rectangle(11,22,55,55));
   rects.Add(new Rectangle(66,22,55,55));
   //..
```

And check in the MouseClick event:

```
private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Rectangle r in rects)
        if (r.Contains(e.Location))
        {
            // do things here
            Console.WriteLine("You have hit Rectangle no.: " + rects.IndexOf(r));
        }
}
```

If you want to you can create a more complex class (or struct) to hold more than just a List of Rectangles and store other data with them, like an ID or other params or maybe even delegates pointing to the actions you want to do..

For more complex imagemaps I found the simplest and yet most powerful way is to create them as Bitmaps in the same size as the Image, color them as needed and them read out the colors by using the MouseClick location as a lookup into the Bitmap which is held in memory..

**update:** For the image posted the simplest solution is to create a List and check against it:

```
List<Color> colors = new List<Color>();
```

Add the colors:

```
colors.Add(Color.Brown);
//..


private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

   Color cHit = ((Bitmap)this.BackgroundImage).GetPixel(e.X, e.Y);
    foreach (Color c in colors )
        if (cHit .ToArgb() == c.ToArgb())
        {
            // do things here
            Console.WriteLine("You have hit Rectangle no.: " + colors .IndexOf(c) + " with Color " + cHit.ToString());
        }
```

Obviously this will only work if the color list has the **same** colors as the image! Easy if you create the image yourself; otherwise you will again need to take care to create the list properly!

**Note**: If you are using the `Form.BackgroundImage` make sure to set the `BackgroundImageLayout` to `None` or else the coordinates of the mouse click will not match those of the pixels in the image! If you want to `Center` it you need to calculate the offsets! Using a `Panel` or a `PictureBox` is much more flexible..

Comment: what if you don't know the coordinates of the boxes? Is there a way you can capture the mouse click's 'MouseEventArgs e' to determine the row and column of each of the rectangles in the background image?

Comment: You mean they are __in__ the image? if they have really distinct colors you can use the aproach to read their colors with Color c = ((Bitmap)PictureBox.Image).GetPixel(e.X, .Y);

Comment: Yes, the color boxes are IN the image. So if you used the approach to read the color, would you read the color into the mouse click event for the form?

Comment: You need to know something about where they are! One way is to write an tiny editor: click and drag over each box and write the coodinates of mouse down and mouseup to a file.. Cam you post a link to the image somewhere?

Comment: Note, that I hade assumed you use a `PictureBox`. Looks like you use the ` Form` directly, though. I have changed the answer accordingly and added a note about `BackGroundImageLayout`!

Answer (score 0):

you need to have canvases on your image . make fixed sizes canvases , attach events on it

Comment: OP needs a WinForms application, not WPF.

Comment: or she can use a rectangle or as u say picturebox...anyhow some control should be there